# Select top fraction n rows (by value) but if the fraction of n rows is lower than 1 keep all rows

Tags: r, dplyr

As an example I have this data.frame

```
df <- structure(list(var_1 = c(7578L, 21L, 4534L, 53L, 457L, 621L, 
                               878L, 636L, 1111L, 25L, 23L, 99L), var_2 = c(1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 
                                                                            2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
                                                                                                                                                  -12L))
```

I want to group by var_2 and then find the top 30% of each group. But if 30% of the rows of an group is less than 1, then I want to keep all rows.

So I made this function (adapted from the top_n function of dplyr):

```
top_frac_keep_lower <- function(x, n, wt) {
  if ((nrow(x) * {{ n }}) < 1) {
    x
  } else {
    top_frac(x, {{ n }}, {{ wt }})
  }
}
```

The function works if you first filter for one of the groups in var_2:

```
df_var_2_1 <- filter(df, df$var_2 == 1)
top_frac_keep_lower(df_var_2_2, 0.3, var_1)

 var_1 var_2
1  7578     1
2    21     1

df_var_2_2 <- filter(df, df$var_2 == 2)
top_frac_keep_lower(df_var_2_2, 0.3, var_1)

  var_1 var_2
1  4534     2
2   878     2
3  1111     2
```

But if you use grouped_by it does not work:

```
df %>% 
  group_by(var_2) %>% 
  top_frac_keep_lower(n = 0.3, var_1)

# A tibble: 3 x 2
# Groups:   var_2 [1]
  var_1 var_2
  <int> <int>
1  4534     2
2   878     2
3  1111     2
```

So why does this not work? What am I missing?

Comment: Just a few comments. I would suggest changing the parameter named n to p or something else. Typically n implies a count so it's unexpected to use it as a percent. I'm also not sure why you're wrapping some values inside two curly braces. It won't hurt anything but I don't see why it's necessary and once again... Kind of confusing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use `group_split` as the function uses `nrow`

```
library(purrr)
library(dplyr)
df %>% 
 group_split(var_2) %>% 
  map_dfr(top_frac_keep_lower, n = 0.3, var_1)
```

Comment: Thanks this works! But is there also a way to make the function work with group_by?

Comment: @Artie16  For that, the function `top_frac_keep_lower` may need some changes

Comment: Yes indeed. But how? What I think should be done is to check if the number of elements in one of the groups multiplied by n is lower than 1. But how do you get this information? `nrow` doesn't work with `group_by` and `count(x)[2]` gives an error: `the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used`

Comment: @Artie16  You could use `do` but it would be more efficient with `map` i.e. `df %>% group_by(var_2) %>% do(if((nrow(.) * 0.3) < 1 ) . else top_frac(., n = 0.3, .$var_1))`